# Relatedlist in pageblocktable

Tags: visualforce

I have a pageblocktable in Vf page where accounts records are rendered.
I have Zip code as Child object for Account object .

Now I want to show the relatedlist in that Vf page where the related list are shown

What is the best layout and wayout to do this.??

Comment: Note--The relatedlist that I want to show is in pageblocktable..

Answer (score 3):

Class:

```
List<Account> acc { get; set; }

public YourClass()
{
    acc = [ Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From ZipCodes__r) From Account ];
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
    <apex:column value="{!a.id}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="2" style="background:#eee;">
        <b>Related ZIP codes: </b>
        <apex:repeat value="{!a.ZipCodes__r}" var="z">
            {!z.Name}, 
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can't tell you what layout is the best ;) One option would be to have 2 columns and use the [standard tag for the related list](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm):

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
    <apex:column value="{!a.Name}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="ZIP Codes">
        <apex:relatedList subject="{!a.Id}" list="ZIP_Codes__r" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You can style it a bit, for example to remove the header images from the list use the title attribute... Or if you want - embed another pageblocktable, repeat tag etc and have full control over the styling.